# Adjust context switch frequency in Java on Linux

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, debugging

I'm looking into a potential concurrency issue in some binary Java code. The code sometimes has a strange behavior, but I'm not sure if it's actually due to concurrency issues in the code itself, or if it's something else. I haven't been able to reproduce the strange behavior myself, but only seen it happening in our log files.

Is there a way to up the context switch frequency of the JVM, in order to surface potential concurrency issues with higher probability? Preferably doing this without explicitly inserting calls to Thread::yeild or Thread::sleep in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Thread-weaver](https://code.google.com/archive/p/thread-weaver/wikis/UsersGuide.wiki) test framework can help you. It's been a while since I've experimented with it, but it does allow you to force a particular scheduling. It can also be run in a sort of default mode where a lot of interleavings between two methods are tested.

This is a simple example test (using default interleaving)

```
public class MyListTest {
    private MyList<String> list;

    @Test
    public void testThreading() {
        AnnotatedTestRunner runner = new AnnotatedTestRunner();
        // Run all Weaver tests in this class, using MyList as the Class Under Test.
        runner.runTests(this.getClass(), MyList.class);
    }

    @ThreadedBefore
    public void before() {
        list = new MyList<>();
    }

    @ThreadedMain
    public void mainThread() {
        list.putIfAbsent("A");
    }

    @ThreadedSecondary
    public void secondThread() {
        list.putIfAbsent("A");
    }

    @ThreadedAfter
    public void after() {
        assertThat(list).hasSize(1);
    }
}
```